# Не могу добавить BLOB fule MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLDataException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

/**
 * Created by roysez on 08.02.2017.
 */
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); // гурхить драйвер в память
            String userName = "root";
            String userPassword = "somepassword";
            String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test3";
            Connection databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,userName,userPassword);
            PreparedStatement addCVStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement("update students SET cv=? where first_name='Sergiy' and last_name='Balukh'");
            File pdfFile = new File("C:\\Users\\roysez\\Downloads\\SergiyBalukhCV.pdf");
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
            addCVStatement.setBinaryStream(1,input,pdfFile.length());
            addCVStatement.executeUpdate();
           databaseConnection.commit();
        }catch (MySQLDataException e ){
           e.printStackTrace();

        } catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Не могу никак решить проблему, все такие темы преесмотрел, ничего не помагает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте используемую версию mysql-connector, должна быть 5.1.x и выше, вроде как в 5.0 метод setBinaryStream не поддерживается.